# How to arrange SQL data?

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a SQL table name MarketRates. In this table has one column, the name is `Rate`. Each month the rate will change. I have solved this issue. My doubt is any other better solution for this. My table schema and data like

[image]

The same way I have a lot of records. My problem is the same name has multiple rows. Any other better solution for this?

Comment: possibly look at second normal form to split this into two tables. one holding the market names and one holding monthly rates with a foreign key between them?

Comment: Please mention how to solved this issue only when you will get second opinion.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of data - copy-and-paste as text here to make it accessible for people having img sharing sites blocked by their corp network.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to understand your question but I think you are asking about database normalization.

> Database normalization, or simply normalization, is the process of restructuring a relational database in accordance with a series of so-called normal forms in order to reduce data redundancy and improve data integrity.

There are many articles on the internet on how to normalize a database. How and when you normalize a database is up to you and the requirements.

You will probably need to move the market information into its own table

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're asking for suggestions on normalizing the database for when it grows.

An example would be if you've got millions of records and a lot of them have a rate of 1 and a lot of others have a rate of 2 and more have other rates and you want to update them all quickly.
Running the query below might take a bit too long to run in some situations:

```
update MarketRates set rate = @NewRate where rate = @OldRate
```

So to make this more efficient you'd rather have a separate table that contains all of the rates and a primary key, then instead of having your rate in MarketRates you'd have the matching foreign key.

Then when you're querying the table you'd join it to this rates table on that foreign key = primary key relationship.

Now when you want to update the rate for millions of entries in MarketRates you only have to update the single entry in the rates table and MarketRates will be looking at that single place to get the updated rate.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of normalization, one solution would be the following, where the MarketRates table contains foreign keys to both the Markets table and the Rates table:

```
table Markets (
    Id integer,
    Name varchar(128)
)

table Rates (
    Id integer,
    Rate numeric,
    Year integer,
    Month varchar(20)
)

table MarketRates (
    FK_MarketId integer,
    FK_RateId integer
)
```

One advantage of having three tables (as opposed to only two) is that if a given rate is used in more than one market, you avoid duplication of rates across markets as well. Personally, I would store the month as an integer value, but that is partly beside the point here.